# How to move a panorama item closer to the panorama title

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, panorama-control

I have a panorama view with a title and no headers for the items. Now there is a big gap between the title (applicationTitle) and the content. Is there a way to move the content closer to the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this with Pivot. Dont see why you can't with Panorama.

Use `Margin="0, -100, 0, 0"` . This will move your panorama a bit higher and overlap with existing control. Adjust the Top of margin to your desired value.

Comment: Thanks! Never occured to me using negative values for margin. Works great.

Comment: Any idea if you want to put the title in top of the content?, using margin="0,-200,0,0" the content overlaps the title and I want the other way around.

Comment: you have to remember that XAML order of rendering is dependent on the order you set for objects. Title is defined before content hence Content overlaps title. Move the title to after content and you will get what you want